# How auto sort checkbox list in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML form default checkbox and other add dynamically but when check checkbox after checkbox order in list shuffled. How to sort this in As-sending order when load page.

HTML Code is Here:

```
<div class="checkbox-list" style="width: auto; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">
   <label><div class="checker" id="uniform-ch2"><span><input type="checkbox" id="ch2" name="data[chk_name][]" value="Further Review"></span></div>Further Review</label>
   <label><div class="checker" id="uniform-ch3"><span><input type="checkbox" id="ch3" name="data[chk_name][]" value="Hot Doc"></span></div>Hot Doc</label>
   <label><div class="checker" id="uniform-ch4"><span><input type="checkbox" id="ch4" name="data[chk_name][]" value="Potential Exhiit"></span></div>Potential Exhibit</label>
   <label><div class="checker" id="uniform-ch1"><span class="checked"><input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="data[chk_name][]" checked="" value="Relevant"></span></div>Relevant</label>                             
   <label><div class="checker" id="uniform-ch5"><span class="checked"><input type="checkbox" id="ch5" name="data[chk_name][]" checked="" value="test"></span></div>test</label> 
</div>
```

JavaScript Code File :

```
 $(".checkbox-list lable").sort(function(a, b) {
   return parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id);
   }).each(function() {
   var elem = $(this);
   elem.remove();
   $(elem).appendTo(".checkbox-list");
 });
```

Sort Order by id="uniform-ch2" Asc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort it like this:

```
<script>
    $(".checkbox-list label").sort(function(a, b) {
       return ($(a).find(".checker").attr("id")) > ($(b).find(".checker").attr("id"));
       }).appendTo(".checkbox-list");
</script>
```

You had several problems in your script:

- You mistyped `lable` in the selector
- You were comparing the IDs of `label`, not `.checker`
- You were parsing the IDs, so you were getting NaN and, thus, no sorting.
- Looping through the labels at the end was unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes:

1. spelling of `label` is `lable` ,which is wrong

   ```
   $(".checkbox-list lable")
   ```
2. `parseInt(a.id)` will return `id` of the label, which is not assigned. So, you need to assign `id` value to label. Something like

   ```
   <label id="1">
   ```

[**>>>Demo<<<**](https://jsfiddle.net/nyyw9auc/)